# Python vs matplotlib - Chart generation issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the below python code. but as an output it gives a chart like in the attachment. And its really messy in python. Can anybody tell me hw to fix the issue and make the day in ascenting order in X axis?

```
   import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df = pd.read_excel("C/desktop/data.xlsx")
    df = df.loc[df['month'] == 8]
    df = df.astype({'day': str})
    plt.plot( 'day', 'cases', data=df)
```

In the first instance, i didnt take the day as str. So it came like this.
[image]

Because it had decimal numbers, i have converted it to str. now this happens.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you convert `'day'` to `str` type?

Comment: Hi @Dm, i have updated the post for your answer. Thats because to remove decimalvalues

Comment: Converting to `str` is a bad idea, as matplotlib orders them in the same order as it encounters them.  Your data seem to have multiple entries for the same 'day' (maybe different years?), and, moreover, the days aren't sorted. Matplotlib connects the values in the same order as they are encountered.  You might try to sort your dataframe on 'day'.

Comment: Please provide an example of your dataset. How many points per day do you have?

Answer (score 1):

What you got is typical of an unsorted dataset with many points per group.
As you did not provide an example, here is one:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.random.randint(1,21,size=100),
                   'cases': np.random.randint(0,50000,size=100),
                   })
plt.plot('day', 'cases', data=df)
```

[image: initial plot]

There is no reason to plot a line in this case, you can use a scatter plot instead:

```
plt.scatter('day', 'cases', data=df)
```

[image: scatter plot]

To make more sense of your data, you can also compute an aggregated value (ex. mean):

```
plt.plot('day', 'cases', data=df.groupby('day', as_index=False)['cases'].mean())
```

[image]